# SPSS Analysing different combinations of multiple responses

Tags: spss, survey

I am using SPSS to do survey analysis. I won't study different combinations of choices of a multiple response question.

For example, the multiple response question could be "Tick the countries you've been to, say US, China, Japan". Of course this is a multiple response question as respondents are allowed to tick more than one of the three questions.

I know how to deal with multiple response question in general case, say Define Variable Sets, Frequency analysis, crosstab analysis.

Is there any method in SPSS to get the frequency (also crosstabs with other questions) of different combination of the three choices, US, China, JP. For instance, how many respondents has been to both US and China, or US and JP, or US only, China Only, or all of the three countries. So in total it should have 7 combinations including been to each country only.

Hope my description is clear enough!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest, you create a variable in wich all possible combinations of answers are coded.

I assume that your multiple response data is stored like this:

```
US JP CHINA
1  0  1
0  0  1
1  1  0
```

Where "1" indicates that a person has been in that country.

Your combi variable would then created like this.

```
COMPUTE visited_combi = US*100 + JP*10 + CHINA.
VARIABLE LABELS visited_combi
   0   "visited neather China, Japan or USA"
   1   "visited China only"
   10  "visited Japan only"
   100 "visited USA only"
   11  "visited China and Japan"
   101 "visited China and USA"
   110 "visited Japan and USA"
   111 "visited China, Japan and USA"
.
```

Now you can run a normal frequency on "visited_combi".